# pip install render not working

Tags: python, pip, installation, render

Simple question I'm sure but I am getting the error below when trying to run 'pip install render' on my Mac terminal.

```
    pip install render
Collecting render
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement render (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for render
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: pip3 install -U pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 887kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.3
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1

Comment: Have you tried `pip install render==v1.0.0 `

Comment: Thanks... So I seemed to have installed it (see below) but my Pycharm is not recognising the install?

Comment: richardrycesMBP:~ Richard$ pip3 install render
Collecting render
  Collecting pyyaml (from render)
  Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->render)
  
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, jinja2, pyyaml, render
  .....
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 jinja2-2.10 pyyaml-3.12 render-1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In your SETTINGS include the following in your Build command:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

and the following in your Start command

```
streamlit run main.py
```

[image: Render's SETTINGS for Command, Build and Start]